# jquery mousemove fires along with mousedown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to detect dragging vs click on a div. I am trying this code,

```
<div id="ab" style="height:200px;width:200px;background:red;">

      <div class="square" style="height:100px;width:100px;background:blue;margin:50px;"> </div>
</div>

var isDragging = false;
$("#ab").on("mousedown",".square", function(e) {    
            console.log("clicked");
            $(window).mousemove(function(m) {
                isDragging = true;
                $(window).unbind("mousemove");
                console.log("moving");
            });
         }).on("mouseup",".square",function(e) {

            var target = $( e.target );
            var wasDragging = isDragging;
            isDragging = false;
            $(window).unbind("mousemove");
            console.log("mosueup");         
            }
        });
```

But it seems to be triggering mousemove right when I click. On Searching, I came across lots of questions, and I tried few fiddles, eg

http://jsfiddle.net/W7tvD/1868/

but if you look at the console, mousemove seems to be triggered right when mousedown is detected. I also tried few other fiddles I found from SO
https://jsfiddle.net/n4820hsh/

But same issue. Am I doing something wrong? Reason I want to do this is, I have the div set to draggable using jquery-ui (Not in here, but for my actual code), but has a different function on click.

Comment: I don't have any problems with the linked fiddle. Only mousedown is triggered on mousedown.

Comment: Huh! thats so wierd. I was working on chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m, and I found this error. AFter your comment, I tried the fiddle on firefox, and it is working fine on firefox!

Comment: @Tyr what browser did you try this on?

Comment: @ aVC: It was firefox. Chrome and MS Edge is working also.